# php date function

Tags: php, datetime

I am using date function to find current time as date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

I want to find 15 mint from now using PHP using date function

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+15 minutes'))
```

Comment: you are right...actually I have a time in database and I want to add 15 mints from that time. Lets say I want to add 15 mints from 2010-12-07 17:54:10. What I have to write then?

Comment: date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('2010-12-07 17:54:10')+60*15)

Answer (score 2):

[strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime) is your friend here.  It will parse all kinds of input and give you a time using plain English.

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+15 minutes'))
```

Comment: you are right...actually I have a time in database and I want to add 15 mints from that time. Lets say I want to add 15 mints from 2010-12-07 17:54:10. What I have to write then?

Comment: In this case, you can pass the timestamp as a second paramater to strtotime(): `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+15 minutes', $timestamp))`... assuming the time is stored in the database as an integer.  If it's in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss then use @stillstanding's code.